# Pointer to non-virtual function of base class

Tags: c++

Code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct A
{
    void f() { std::cout << "A\n"; }
};

struct B : public A
{
    void f() { std::cout << "B\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    void (A::*pf)() = static_cast<void(A::*)()>(&B::f);
    A* p = new B;
    (p->*pf)(); // (1)
}
```

Surprisingly, line `(1)` prints `B`, but, is it undefined behaviour, or even ill-formed code? It seems very surprising that it calls the "wrong" function just because `this` and `pf` points inside `B`, while all static types points inside `A`. Shoudn't the static types lead here?

Comment: @Evg The linked question is about when the base function is virtual.

Comment: This one is closer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46187833/is-it-legal-to-cast-a-pointer-to-derived-class-member-variable-to-a-pointer-to-b - The dynamic type of the object is `B`, so it's all very valid.

Comment: @SebastianRedl There is a discrepancy between the title and the code. The title mentions a virtual function.

Comment: @Evg Right. Fixed now.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Yes your link solves my problem.

Comment: StoryTeller's linked question indeed answers the "is it undefined or even ill-formed?" question. (Nope, it's fine.) The other part of the question is "why does this call `B::f`?".

Comment: @SebastianRedl Once knowing that it's correct as far as the function pointer "points inside" the base pointer (the runtime value of pf points is inside the runtime value of p), it works because I'm calling `pf` what it's inside in the address, which is precisely `B::f`.